# How to calculate converted value for each number in a set using a conversion rate, having its sum equal exactly a rounded fixed converted total?

Tags: arithmetic, computational-mathematics, floating-point, machine-precision

Say I have three numeric values: a total, converted total, and a conversion rate. These are fixed, given numbers, and the two totals always have the precision of two decimal places.

```
total = 1084.50
conversionRate = 17.89057
convertedTotal = 1084.50 / 17.89057 = 60.618526967
convertedTotal = 60.62
```

Say I have $N$ numbers of which their sum equates to the variable total before conversion. These numbers will always be given, are always rounded two decimal places, and will always equal total.

```
n1 = 300.50
n2 = 300.00
n3 = 58.00
n4 = 103.00
n5 = 323.00

n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 = 1084.50 or total
n1+n2+...nx = total
```

I would like to calculate the converted value for each/any number $n_1,\cdots,n_x$ using floating point division given conversion rate, converted total, or both. However, I would like the sum of converted $n_1,\cdots,n_x$ to always equal exactly the converted total, which is rounded to two decimal places.

For below, $c$ represents that the number has been converted using the conversion rate, or ($n/$total)*convertedTotal. .XX represents that the value should be rounded to two decimal places.

```
cn1 = n1/conversionRate

or

cn1 = (n1/total)*convertedTotal # which I believe would always be precise enough for two decimal places
```

This is what I seek, only as precise as computationally possible:

```
cn1.XX + cn2.XX + cn3.XX + cn4.XX + cn5.XX = convertedTotal # convertedTotal is rounded two decimal places so convertedTotal.XX is also appropriate
```

This is definitely a question of precision. I am not sure if I should take a programming/computing data type or pure mathematical approach, or if this is a very simple question.

Comment: Not so different from the "apportionment problem" for the United States Congress. Take the US population, divide by $435$ (the number of seats in Congress) to get the conversion rate, divide each state's population by the conversion rate to get the number of seats that state gets. But each state must get a whole number of seats, so the numbers have to be rounded in some way, but the rounded numbers still have to add up to exactly $435$. There has been a lot of argument over the years as to the right way to do this.

Comment: As I was typing it, I had a feeling it was one of those things. I’ve asked questions before and was met with the similar answers. Maybe I will play around with a few things, a kind thank you for this information @Garry Myerson